# Personification of cold

Tags: personification

I'm looking for terms that personify cold.  For example, 'the cold bit at my nose'.  They will be part of a post/article on the cold weather, so the more options the better.

Edit: see comments below, which both answer the question and indicate why this is flagged as 'too broad'.

Comment: 'biting cold' doesn't look like a "personification."

Comment: As I understand it, you can personify anything, all you have to do is add a human characteristic, so the cold can *bite*; *sting*; *swim*; *rush*; *blow*; *snap* etc. and then you add an adverb: angrily, happily, merrily, evilly, wickedly, cheerfully e.g "The cold snapped angrily at the trees".

Comment: If instead you looking for book/film/TV *characters* who personify *cold* then that is a slightly different request. E.g. the White Witch of Narnia

Comment: @Mari-LouA, those terms are exactly what I'm seeking!  Have you any others in your memory banks besides sting, bite, and snap?  I see this is on hold, but thanks for these at the least....

Comment: There are no limits to the verbs you can use, such as: fly, blow, sweep, march, rush, pace. Then look up each verb in a thesaurus, and *Bob's your uncle*!

Comment: Well done.  This is both the answer to the question _and_ the basis for the question being considered too broad.

Comment: @Minnow Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/209689/edit) the original post to include the additional information if you wish to have this question reopened. Material in comments should be treated as transient; it is not part of the question.

Comment: @choster Thanks, I'm ok with it is being closed.  I appreciate why it was closed and have a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

*Jack Frost* is one.

> Jack Frost is the personification of frost, ice, snow, sleet, and freezing cold weather, a variant of Old Man Winter held responsible for frosty weather, for nipping the nose and toes in such weather, coloring the foliage in autumn, and leaving fernlike patterns on cold windows in winter.

from [Jack Frost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Frost)

Comment: +1 That is one I'll add to the list.  Was hoping for more than one, so I'll keep this open for now.

Answer (score -1):

Chilled to the bone.
Freezing my butt (or bollocks/balls) off.
My/your feet are stone cold.
It's colder than a well-digger's arse. (or Witch's titty.)

These are all I can think of for now.

Comment: Although the -1 is not from me, I don't think those are personification.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but 'freeze my butt off' is hyperbole and 'colder than a ___' is a simile.

Comment: @Minnow I must have misunderstood what you were asking for. No biggie. ¦)